# If I have 2 same name taxonomy term which is used with nodes. how to set only one instead of both?

Tags: nodes, forms, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 taxonomy terms with the same name (*knight(2)* and *knight(6)*) in my Drupal 8 Project; both terms have been used with nodes.

I want to replace *knight(6)* with *knight(2)* in all the nodes. I created the following custom form.

> [image: screenshot]

The submission handler code is the following one.

```php
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  
  $values =  $form_state->getValues();
  $old_term = $values['old_taxonomy_term'];
  $new_term = $values['new_taxonomy_term'];
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type','a')
    ->condition('field_taxonomy_', $old_term, '=');
  $results = $query->execute();

  foreach ($results as $nid) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
    $abc = $node->get('field_taxonomy_')->referencedEntities(); 
    foreach ($abc as $key => $value) {
      $value = reset($value);
      if ($key['tid'] == $old_term) {
        $node->set('field_taxonomy_',$new_term);
        $node->save();
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

The code doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of deleting the other question, and re-asking a duplicate question, you should have edited the existing question. Deleted questions with a negative score may question-ban you, which means you cannot ask anymore questions, as it happened in this case.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Your Point Noted. Sorry! As a new contributor, I Hadn't idea about that. Even I tried to edit the previous question but it was showing me your question is closed.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Closed questions can still be edited, as correcting an off-topic question to make it on-topic is the correct action to take.

Comment: What is `$abc` lol. You're actually loading the term objects with `->referencedEntities();` you should instead be doing `->getValue();`

Comment: @NoSssweat I had declared $abc variable for dump() the data. please take it, easy man. I am just a beginner.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you already edited existing question from your side. so, what I should edit the previous question with the same details by making it undelete, and have to delete this existing question?

Comment: It's too late to do that now. You should have done it instead of deleting the previous question. My previous comment was to confirm that closed questions can still be edited. It's not that closed questions can only be deleted; they can be edited and voted to be re-opened.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Extremely sorry for some miss understandings. I'll take care of those things from the very next time.